# Create a yearly mean variable in a data frame for all countries in a sample

Tags: group-by, mean, mutate

I have a dataset containing a variable which measures the total number of demonstration events (variable "events") that occurred in a given sub-Saharan African country in a given year. I would like to create a new variable measuring the mean level of "events" throughout the sample in a given year.

Here is my dataset

```
   cown year   gdp_usd tor_usd tmr_usd protests riots intensity_level polity gdppc_usd 
1:  404 1997 268550998       0       0        0     2               0     12  231.0229    
2:  404 2000 371095510       0       0        1     1               0     15  301.4956    
3:  404 2003 477458599       0       0        2     0               0      9  362.9062    
4:  404 2004 532062927       0       0        1     1               0      9  394.9958    
5:  404 2005 587029054       0       0       10     2               0     16  425.4719    
6:  404 2006 592365688       0       0        3     0               0     16  418.9021    

    gdp_growth events log_tmr_usd log_tor_usd log_gdppc_usd polity_dummy lag_events
1: 0.065000000      2           0           0      5.442517            0          2
2: 0.054269874      2           0           0      5.708755            0          4
3: 0.005685102      2           0           0      5.894144            0          1
4: 0.027614020      2           0           0      5.978875            0          2
5: 0.042660989     12           0           0      6.053199            0          2
6: 0.023093580      3           0           0      6.037637            0         12
```

I tried with the following code but it didn't work, I got only NAs.

`panel_data7 <- panel_data7 %>%  group_by(year) %>%   mutate(mean_events = mean(events))`